# Do reviewers see other reviewer's comments/scores?

Tags: conference, peer-review

I have read that reviewers actually see other reviewers' comments during reviewing process of a conference (e.g. via easychair website). If that is the case; is that including the scores too? If so, wouldn't that affect the reviewer's decision?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, in easychair, once you submit your own review, you can see all of the information (reviewer names, reviewer scores, reviewer comments) that others have submitted. There is then often a conference call where the review committee (including all reviewers) discusses the merits of each paper in view of all of the reviews and scores, to make a decision about each paper.

Because one has to upload one's own review before seeing the other reviewers' scores and comments, there is a certain amount of insulation from group think. But in the end, the model of easychair is that all reviewers together take on the role of editor, and that they have to come to a conclusion. That is, I think, a valid model to deal with identifying good and bad papers. My experience is that it is no worse than separating the role of the editor from that of reviewers.

Comment: "they have to come to a conclusion" In my field, it's also quite common that the reviewers "agree to disagree" and leave the final decision to someone else (the program chairs or a program board). But per default, they are indeed encouraged to find a consensus.